# Exist condition in SilverStripe

Tags: php, many-to-many, silverstripe

When in the CMS, GridField pagination works using Ajax. When I tick some boxes on one page and navigate to the next, those boxes are no longer ticked.

To overcome that I use offset and limit to handle records in each page. However, there is a problem. For example:

```
Class X { many_many = Y }            -> Table X (X_id)
Class Y { belongs_many_many = X }    -> Table Y (Y_id, Sort)
Table X_Y (X_id, Y_id)
```

As you can guess, when in CMS, the Y records are listed based on Sort, but not in table X_Y where X, Y are listed based on Y_id.

The question is, how can I cause change only to the X_Y table, using the GridField of Y records, regard the current pagination page only?

Comment: afaik you cannot access the manymany table directly using the ORM, however, you can split up the many_many in two has_many relations with a seperate dataobject in between...